# Disable access to another Hard Drive Disks on Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, ssd, mount

I want to install some Linux disto into SSD disk, but I have another SSD with Windows, which I want to disable/unmount during running on Linux...

Is there are some configs where I can set 1st SSD (with Windows) down after BIOS boot sequence?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to unmount it, security, possible file deletion?

Comment: "file deletion" - yes, it's one of the reason.